# Android layout sign in button

Tags: android, android-layout

I have one xml file in which I added one relative layout and  below this I  have two buttons.
one is Signin and the other is newuser and signin button is showing some problem

I set the signin button to the left of newuser button , but its coming down   ,even I tried with layout_marginTop= -42 while running the application its as it is, I mean its not staying to the left of newuser button
 ,The two buttons should be between center and bottom

please help me,Thanks..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_one" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="User Name:"/>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_two" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_below="@+id/ll_one">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Password:"/>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/EditText02"
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:password="true"
    android:inputType="textPassword"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_three" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:text="New user"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
 </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Edited**

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_three" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_below="@+id/ll_two" android:gravity="center">
    <Button 
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:text="New user"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

You are looking for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the two buttons in a horizontal LinearLayout and set their **layout_weight** both to 1. Setting the same weight to the `View`s in a `LinearLayout` makes them take 50% of the space accordingly. Then you can take this "button panel" as a whole.

The following is a sample:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip">     

    ....................

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"              
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
     </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That can be done by adjusting the alignment and width of this "button panel".